# Cypress testing laravel web app problem with dynamic CSS

Tags: css, laravel, cypress

[image: input fields that I need to catch]

In the .vue file in laravel, this input filed is defined here:

```
    <div class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row">
        <div v-if="cargo" class="lg:w-1/2 w-full mb-2 lg:mb-0 " :class="{'lg:p-2' : cargo, '' : !cargo}">
            <vue-google-autocomplete
                    v-if="googleLoaded"
                    class="address-field"
                    types=""
                    :id="'address'+id"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    classname="w-full box-border form-control form-input form-input-bordered"
                    placeholder="Začnite písať adresu..."
                    v-on:placechanged="setAddress"
                    v-on:error="handleAutocompleteError"
            >
            </vue-google-autocomplete>
        </div>
```

my problem is this: :id="'address'+id" it means every time the CSS ID is different, and I need to change it every time in my test for it to work. they go in sequence, but its always another numbers (9 10 11 or 13 14 15 etc)
There is nothing else that differs except this ID for all 3 fields on the page, so i am unable to identify them when the ID is changing each time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach you could try is the [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```js
cy.get('input[id^="address"]')         // select on just the initial part of the id
```

If that has problems (maybe multiple ids starting with "address"), you can add some code in Vue's mounted hook that exposes the full id as a window property, then Cypress can read the exact id during each test run.

---

You can also switch to placeholder for selecting

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder="Začnite písať adresu..."])
```